# Can i tell my Linux machine use only Physical Cores?

Tags: rhel, kernel, cpu, cpu-frequency

I have a Linux Machine with 2 X5650 2.7GHZ Processors and I host game servers on it for my gaming community, and there comes my issue:
game servers need best 1 core performance, but I have 24 vCORES and 12 Physical Cores.
Is it possible to "tell" kernel use 12 physical cores? and then 1 physical core will use 2VCORES?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: @dsstorefile I run 15 game servers and my machine have 12 cores and 24 threads. I want the game servers to spread between 12 cores and not between 24 threads - for best performance.

Comment: I believe each of the "servers" are merely separate applications running on one operating system.

Comment: @dsstorefile it cannot be done globally? without pinning processes to a specific core?

Comment: @dsstorefile Linux kernel does spread the load across cores, but the system spread the loads between all the 24 threads, I want the kernel use only 12 physical cores, not 24.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `taskset` to manually distribute processes across cores by setting their thread affinities. To figure out which threads belong to which cores and processors, check `/proc/cpuinfo` as shown below:

```
$ grep -E '^processor|^physical id|^core id' /proc/cpuinfo |sed 's/^processor/\nprocessor/'

processor       : 0
physical id     : 0
core id         : 0

processor       : 1
physical id     : 0
core id         : 1

processor       : 2
physical id     : 0
core id         : 0

processor       : 3
physical id     : 0
core id         : 1
$ _
```

`processor` is the thread number, `physical id` is the physical CPU number, and `core id` is the core number. The above output comes from a machine with a single CPU with two cores and four threads.

`taskset` can be used as `taskset --all-tasks -p <hex_mask> <pid>` to modify the affinity of all threads of an extant process. The `hex_mask` is a bitmask where each 1 bit represents an assigned CPU thread and numbering starts from the right. For instance, `0xa` for the mask means binary `0b1010` which indicates an affinity of thread #1 and thread #3 for the process. The PID, I hope, is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

### Virtual Cores or "Threads"

If you want to avoid virtual cores or "threads", then you could simply disable the feature. Although, disabling this feature not necessarily will improve performance, that depends on the server software you are running (there are engines that work better with HT/SMT, while others don't), you should probably test it.

According to your post, the Intel X5650 has 6 Cores and 12 Threads each. You can verify this with `lscpu`. For ex. the following CPU has 4 Cores and the HT disabled:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
```

You can verify the HT cores by running:

```
# grep -H . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/topology/thread_siblings_list
```

This will output something like:

```
$  grep -H . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/topology/thread_siblings_list
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/thread_siblings_list:X,Y
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/topology/thread_siblings_list:X,Y
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/topology/thread_siblings_list:X,Y
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/topology/thread_siblings_list:X,Y
```

Where X,Y are Physical-Core-ID,HT-Core-ID, as in: 0,4 (the first virtual core ID usually is the next to the last physical one).

### Disabling Hyper-Threading

With this information you have 2 options to disable the HT, depending on your access to the server:

1. Through the BIOS settings (the easiest)

   - You should check your Motherboard manufacturer manual, and disable the Hyper-Threading there. This requires the server to reboot and access to the BIOS settings.
2. Through the command line (no need to reboot)

   - You could disable each virtual core in Linux directly, create a `disablevcore.sh` file:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for i in {YY..YY}; do
       echo "Disabling logical HT core $i."
       echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu${i}/online;
    done
```

And replace YY..YY for the threads ID you want to disable, according to your processors, probably {6..11}. Although I'm not sure how the numbering works on multi-socket setups, so you should check carefully.

3. Another option (2.a if you will) is to disable it in GRUB:

   - Edit the GRUB config file: `/etc/sysconfig/grub` (if  and append `noht` in the line that starts with: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. It should be something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... noht ..."
```

---

## More about HT and SMT:

### Intel "Hyper-Threading"

> Hyper-threading is Intel's proprietary simultaneous multithreading
>   implementation used to improve parallelization of computations
>   performed on x86 microprocessors. It first appeared in February 2002
>   on Xeon server processors and in November 2002 on Pentium 4 desktop
>   CPUs. Later, Intel included this technology in Itanium, Atom, and Core
>   'i' Series CPUs, among others.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

### AMD "Simultaneus Multithreading (SMT)"

> Simultaneous multithreading is a technique for improving the overall
>   efficiency of superscalar CPUs with hardware multithreading. SMT
>   permits multiple independent threads of execution to better utilize
>   the resources provided by modern processor architectures.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading

### More details on disabling HT through the kernel:

https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/01/how-to-disable-or-enable-hyper.html